# stereo rendering with Vulkan

Tags: vulkan, stereo-3d

I've been looking into stereo rendering using Vulkan, as I'm trying to run some tests on a Quadro M6000. The topic seems to be hardly touched so far, since I'm unable to find any samples or how-to's online, also the Vulkan documentation is very sparse when it comes to the stereo. As the term "stereo" is there always used in conjunction with "multiview", I suppose I have to set up a multiview renderer and use imageArrayLayers, is this correct? In fact, the VK_KHX_multiview extension reads like exactly what I'd like to do, but I don't really know how to exactly initialize the devices and how to interface with them so I get a stereoscopic view in the end of the day. Is there a more straightforward way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do? Is the "old" method of rendering into eye buffers sequentially not available anymore for Vulkan applications?

I guess I don't know where to start and I would highly appreciate if anybody could point me into the right direction or maybe there are even samples I missed.

Comment: "*Is there a more straightforward way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do?*" How is multiview not straightforward? "*Is the "old" method of rendering into eye buffers sequentially not available anymore for Vulkan applications?*" You're using Vulkan presumably because you like performance. Multiview exists to allow hardware acceleration of rasterization of slightly different views at the same time. Sequential rendering would be slower.

Comment: Well, let's just say, coming from OpenGL, Vulkan seems not that straightforward in many ways. My motivation to use it mainly is about parallel tasking, which is quite crutial for my use case, I don't care for rendering speed so much. Let's not argue about my motivations here, I am interested in how I could accomplish what I'm trying to do. So, can you recommend any good samples?

Comment: Multiview is just a way of accelerating drawing slightly different contents (e.g. just different eye positions) to two layers of an image array framebuffer. You can do the same manually without multiview: create two image views, each containing one of the layers, and draw to them one after the other. Are you primarily asking how to then present those two layers to a stereo display so that they're interpreted as the two eye buffers? That's separate from rendering, and you'd need to ask Nvidia or look for documentation from them about how to do that I think.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. Yes, that's in fact what I'm asking. With GL_FRONT/BACK_LEFT/RIGHT in OpenGL there was hardware agnostic support for left/right eye, right? You just had to enable GL_STEREO and were ready to go. I would be surprised if Vulkan does not feature an alternative to this. Do I really have to implement a variation of this explicitly for every graphics hardware I possibly want to run?

Comment: The way it's supposed to work is that you create a layered swapchain (`VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR::imageArrayLayers = 2`). Check `VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::maxImageArrayLayers` first. Then you can draw left/right eye to the two layers of the swapchain images you get from `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`. I've never seen any documentation or samples doing stereo in Vulkan on any hardware, so although this is how it's supposed to work, I didn't want to claim that it actually does work :).

Comment: Note that your GPU / driver may or may not support the multiview extension. The [Vulkan Hardware Database](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=VK_KHX_multiview) is a useful resource for checking on that.